# Condition for the pair of lines $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ to be parallel

Tags: geometry

> Show that the condition for the pair of lines $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ to be parallel is $ab=h^2$ and $bg^2=af^2$ or $\dfrac{a}{h}=\dfrac{h}{b}=\dfrac{g}{f}$.

$ab=h^2$ condition is understandable as the acute angle between the lines $\tan\theta=\dfrac{2\sqrt{h^2-ab}}{a+b}$ can be obtained from the corresponding lines going through the origin $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$.

In a similar post [Deriving conditions for a pair of straight lines to be parallel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234545/deriving-conditions-for-a-pair-of-straight-lines-to-be-parallel), it is i think attempted to prove by taking partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$, and taking  $+ℎ+=0$ and
$ℎ++=0$ to be coincident.

I simply do not understand the logic behind such an attempt ?

And how do I prove that the pair of lines represented by the second order equation are parallel or coincident, and is there a better or simpler way to prove this ?

Comment: Coincident is easy: one equation is a nonzero multiple of the other.

Comment: @amd I think the condition $ab=h^2$ does not differentiate whether the lines are coincident or parallel. It just says the angle between the pair of lines is zero. My doubt is in the condition $bg^2=af^2$

Comment: The way you worded that last question, it reads as if you’re asking about “two given pair of lines” generally, not about the degenerate conic equation in particular.

Comment: @amd sorry about that and thanks for the correction, edited OP.

Comment: Note that $\frac ah=\frac hb=\frac gf$ is a stronger condition than $ab=h^2$ and $bg^2=af^2$, because you can flip the sign of either $f$ or $g$ while maintaining both $ab=h^2$ and $bg^2=af^2$, Anyway I don't think the logic behind the attempt to use partial derivatives is valid (at least not the way it was done in the linked question). I have posted an alternative approach there.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the given equation factors as
$$fg=0$$
Partially differentiating by $x$ gives
$$f_xg + fg_x=0$$
Partially differentiating by $y$ gives
$$f_yg+fg_y = 0$$
Just notice that any point which lies on both $f=0$ and $g=0$ also satisfies both above equations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97541/discussion-on-answer-by-ganeshie8-condition-for-the-pair-of-lines-ax22hxyby).