# Pair of straight lines parallel vs coincident

Tags: geometry

> The equation $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ represents a pair of parallel
>    lines if $\dfrac{a}{h}=\dfrac{h}{b}=\dfrac{g}{f}$ and the distance between the parallel lines is $2\sqrt{\dfrac{g^2-ac}{a(a+b)}}$ or $2\sqrt{\dfrac{f^2-bc}{b(a+b)}}$

This is given in many references and have been in discussion with [Deriving conditions for a pair of straight lines to be parallel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234545/deriving-conditions-for-a-pair-of-straight-lines-to-be-parallel)
 and [Condition for the pair of lines $^2+2ℎ+^2+2+2+=0$ to be parallel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322418/condition-for-the-pair-of-lines-ax22hxyby22gx2fyc-0-to-be-parallel/3322448?noredirect=1#comment6842807_3322448).

First part of the statement is attempted to prove as follows:

Let, $l=Ax+By+C=0,k=Dx+Ey+F=0$ be the pair of lines
$$
lk=0
$$
Taking partial derivative w.r.t $x$ resulting in the line:
$$
L_x=lk'_x+l'_xk=0
$$
Taking partial derivative w.r.t $y$ resulting in the line:
$$
L_y=lk'_y+l'_yk=0
$$
Now, $l=0$ and $k=0\implies L_x=0$ and $L_y=0$ : the point of intersection of $l=0,k=0$ are the same as that of $L_x=0,L_y=0$.

$\implies$ when $l=0,k=0$ are coincident, the resulting lines $L_x=0,L_y=0$ are also coincident. ie, all 4 coincide.

$\implies$$\dfrac{a}{h}=\dfrac{h}{b}=\dfrac{g}{f}$

And when $l=0,k=0$ are parallel I don't think we can say much about $L_x=0,L_y=0$ from the equations. So it seems like the condition $\dfrac{a}{h}=\dfrac{h}{b}=\dfrac{g}{f}$ is for coincident lines ?

But plotting an example, check [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/be1vifmsa8), thanx @ganeshie8 for the help, it seems like if $l=0,k=0$ parallel you'll still get coincident $L_x=0,L_y=0$.

It'd be very helpful if someone could help me clarify this ?

Thanx @David K for the post in [Deriving conditions for a pair of straight lines to be parallel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234545/deriving-conditions-for-a-pair-of-straight-lines-to-be-parallel). There it is proved that

> The equation $^2+2ℎ+^2+2+2+=0$ is an equation of two parallel lines if and only if $ℎ^2=, =ℎ, =ℎ$, and $^2≥$

But, I think all these conditions do not say whether the lines are coincident or just parallel ?, please correct me if I am wrong ?

And how do I prove the distance between the lines to be $2\sqrt{\dfrac{g^2-ac}{a(a+b)}}$ or $2\sqrt{\dfrac{f^2-bc}{b(a+b)}}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read your links and their comments before starting an answer.
That would have saved a big waste of time.

I have posted an alternative proof in an answer to
[Deriving conditions for a pair of straight lines to be parallel.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234545/deriving-conditions-for-a-pair-of-straight-lines-to-be-parallel).
I do not think the approach using partial derivatives in that question is a good one.

The condition $\frac ah=\frac hb=\frac gf$ tells us that the equation
$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$
is either the equation of two parallel lines, the equation of
one line (which could be regarded as "two parallel lines" that are coincident),
or *the equation of nothing.*

The question of whether $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ is satisfied by any points at all cannot be answered merely by looking at $a,$ $b,$ $f,$ $g,$ and $h.$
You also have to look at $c.$

If $\frac ah=\frac hb=\frac gf,$ a necessary additional condition to have a solution at all is either $g^2 \geq ac$ or $f^2 \geq bc.$
This could be guessed by looking at the formulas for the distance between the lines, realizing that $a$ and $b$ must have the same sign (because $ab = h$),
and realizing that the expressions inside the square roots are non-negative
only if $g^2 - ac$ or $f^2 - bc$ are non-negative.

An additional condition to have one line instead of two is
either $g^2 = ac$ or $f^2 = bc,$ which puts a zero inside the square root.

---

Regarding the second part of the question, namely, how we can show that the distance between the parallel lines is $2\sqrt{\frac{g^2-ac}{a(a+b)}}$
or $2\sqrt{\frac{f^2-bc}{b(a+b)}}$:

We suppose in all of the following that $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ is the equation of one line or two parallel lines.

For simplicity, let's just consider $2\sqrt{\frac{g^2-ac}{a(a+b)}}$ at first.
This formula obviously works only if $a \neq 0.$ Otherwise you would be dividing by zero. So assume $a\neq 0.$ It follows that $h\neq 0.$

Then as I showed in my answer to [Deriving conditions for a pair of straight lines to be parallel.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234545/deriving-conditions-for-a-pair-of-straight-lines-to-be-parallel),
we can rewrite $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ as
$$
a(x+By)^2 + 2g(x+By) + c = 0
$$
where $B=\frac ha = \frac bh.$
The two lines are parallel to the line $x+By=0$ and perpendicular to the line $Bx-y=0.$ To find the distance between the lines we can take the distance between their intersection points with that perpendicular line.

To find the intersection points of the two lines with $Bx-y=0,$ we can set $y=Bx$ in $a(x+By)^2 + 2g(x+By) + c = 0,$ which gives us the equation
$$
a(x+B^2x)^2 + 2g(x+B^2x) + c = 0.
$$
Solving this as a quadratic in $x+B^2x,$
$$
x+B^2x = \frac{-g \pm \sqrt{g^2 - ac}}{a}.
$$
Pulling the factor $1+B^2 = 1 + \frac ba$ out of each side, we get
$$
x = \frac{-g \pm \sqrt{g^2 - ac}}{a + b}.
$$
Since we have assumed the equation has a solution,
this gives us $x$ coordinates separated by a horizontal distance
$$\Delta x = 2\frac{\sqrt{g^2 - ac}}{a + b}.$$

Meanwhile, since $y = Bx = \left(\sqrt{\frac ba}\right)x$ at the two intersection points with the perpendicular line,
the $y$ coordinates of these points are separated by a vertical distance
$$\Delta y = 2\left(\sqrt{\frac ba}\right)\frac{\sqrt{g^2 - ac}}{a + b}.$$

The total distance between the two intersection points is therefore
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2}
&= \sqrt{4\frac{g^2 - ac}{(a + b)^2}
   + 4\left({\frac ba}\right)\frac{g^2 - ac}{(a + b)^2}} \\
&= \sqrt{4\left({1+\frac ba}\right)\frac{g^2 - ac}{(a + b)^2}} \\
&= 2\sqrt{\left(\frac{a+b}{a}\right)\frac{g^2 - ac}{(a + b)^2}} \\
&= 2\sqrt{\frac{g^2 - ac}{a(a + b)}}.
\end{align}

The proof that the distance is $2\sqrt{\frac{f^2-bc}{b(a+b)}}$ when $b\neq 0$
is similar.

Comment: sorry about the mistakes you have pointed out. have corrected those in OP. Kindly check if it is properly explained.

Comment: You still have not related $L_x$ and $L_y$ to the original lines $l=0$ and $k=0$ in any meaningful way. What you have found is that parallel lines that intersect are coincident. But the interesting case is when they do *not* intersect, that is, you never have $l=0$ and $k=0$ simultaneously.

Comment: `The line $4+5=0$ is not either of the lines given by the equation $(+2)(2+)=0$` I am doubtful if I have not explained something correctly. The lines you have chosen are perpendicular, but I have never meant the resulting line will be one among the pair of lines, unless they are coincident ?

Comment: Regarding your second comment: At the point of intersection of the pair of lines $L_x=lk'_x+l'_xk=0.k'_x+l'_x.0=0$ and $L_y=0\implies$ point of intersection of $L_x=0,L_y=0$ are same as that of $l=0,k=0$. If $l=0,k=0$ are coincident, the points of intersection are the points lie on the given coincident lines, and there we have $L_x=0,L_y=0$ in the similar manner, so in this case I concluded that $L_x=0,L_y=0$ lines on the same line $l=0,k=0$, Is it not right ?

Comment: OK, I believe you are correct that in general $L_x=0$ and $L_y=0$ intersect at the same point as $l=0$ and $k=0,$ **if** $l=0$ and $k=0$ intersect in any point. Also, if the original two lines are parallel, the lines given by the partial derivatives are coincident. I don't think these are actually helpful facts regarding the underlying problem, however. I have made a more complete answer under the earlier linked question, and summarized some useful facts here.

Comment: So the condition $\dfrac{a}{h}=\dfrac{h}{b}=\dfrac{g}{f}$ alone does not differentiate the given pair of lines are parallel or coincident, as in both cases $L_x=0,L_y=0$ are coincident right ?. So if that is the case I think $\dfrac{a}{h}=\dfrac{h}{b}\implies ab=h^2$ 'd suffice for showing pair of lines being parallel or coincident, as $\tan\theta=\dfrac{2\sqrt{h^2-ab}}{a+b}$, right ?

Comment: `The equation $^2+2ℎ+^2+2+2+=0$ is an equation of two parallel lines if and only if $ℎ^2=, =ℎ, =ℎ, and ^2≥$`: this I think what is being proved there in that link. But, I think all these conditions do not say whether the lines are coincident or just parallel ?

Comment: The condition $ab=h^2$ says the two lines are parallel **if you already know you have an equation of two lines**. In the question asked in 2017, it says 
"the pair of straight lines $ax^2+ 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx +2fy+ c = 0$," but in your question you only say "the equation $ax^2+ 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx +2fy+ c = 0$." Do you see how the older question already gives a much stronger condition than you did, even before it says anything about the coefficients? Usually when we have $ax^2+ 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx +2fy+ c = 0$ it is not the equation of two lines at all, parallel or not.

Comment: I thought I was very clear when the lines are coincident or not, but here it is again. If $g^2=ac$ they're coincident. If $g^2<ac$ there are **no** lines; there is no solution at all. The remaining case is $g^2>ac,$ which gives two separate lines.

Comment: Ok I agree.So I think $g^2-ac$ or $f^2-bc$ is what determines the lines to be parallel or coincident, apart from all the other conditions which I think all can be derived from the attempt using partial derivatives and the condition of the second order diff. equation being a pair of lines.

Comment: So how do I prove the distance between the parallel lines is $2\sqrt{\dfrac{g^2-ac}{a(a+b)}}$ or $2\sqrt{\dfrac{f^2-bc}{b(a+b)}}$ ?